# "Size" or "Shape" . Which one is the best?

Tags: meaning

Which one is true? 
Answer this question in meaning aspect.

> a) Your shirt will lose its **size** if you wash it.
>
> b) Your shirt will lose its **shape** if you wash it.

Comment: Hello, snooper. ELU is a site where people asking questions are required to do a reasonable amount of research _before_ asking them (and to give their results). Have you Googled (or examined Ngrams for) "lose its size" and "lose its shape"? // I assume you're asking about the acceptability of the expressions, not the physics involved.

Comment: Either or both could happen quite independently. It depends what the shirt is made of and how carefully you wash it.

Comment: Either it will *shrink* or it will *lose its shape* or both.  "Lose its size" is not at all idiomatic.

Comment: Neither is true or best. The only true and best version is "your shirt will lose its color if you wash it".

Comment: @RegDwigнt that's not true at all. Clothes can lose shape, shrink in size or lose colour in the wash.

Comment: Actually, your shirt will lose it's *mojo* if you wash it.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, people tend to say

> Your shirt will lose its **shape**

However, if you are referring to the act of the shirt becoming smaller, consider:

> Your shirt will **shrink**